# My Facebook "click to post" in the notification center is not working. (Mac OSX 10.8.3)

Tags: macos, facebook, notifications

When i click the "click to tweet" button, it works,
but when i click the "click to post", nothing happens---plus my twitter button wont work afterwards. :( so i have to restart my mac again.
tried removing my fb account then adding it again, but still doesn't work. 
Any solutions?

Comment: Try logging off from Faceboom in System Prefrences and log back in. Could be an authentication issue.

Comment: In your FB set it up to accept the application. In the security log in approvals !